# How can I do something like this photo gallery in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, photo-gallery

The preview of the new accuweather.com has a really cool photo gallery. Anyone have ideas or specific tutorials on how to mimic it?

Here's a link to what I want:

http://www.weatherforyourlife.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a jCarousel inside a Fancy Zoom window...